# Norm of matrix $M= u \otimes v^*$ if $u$ and $v$ are unit norm vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, products, kronecker-product

Let $u$ and $v$ be an $n \times 1$ and $m \times 1$ unit norm (L-2 norm) vectors, respectively.
Let us define matrix $M$ (of dimension $n \times m$) as the kronecker product of $u$ and $v^*$  $$M= u \otimes v^*,$$ where $v^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $v$.

My question: can we claim that the resulting matrix $M$ is of unit norm ?

**Update:**
P.S.: I saw this result in a paper where they don't precise which norm is used for the matrix.

Comment: What norm do you use for matrices?

Comment: And also, what norm for the vectors?

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: @K.Miller but here we have the Kronecker product of $u$ ($n \times 1$) and $v^*$ ($1 \times m$), which results in  an $n \times m$ matrix. I am wrong ?

Comment: Yes, I agree, my mistake, I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
||u\otimes v^*||_{op} &= \sup_{||x||_2\leq 1} ||(u\otimes v^*)(x)||_2\\
&=  \sup_{||x||_2 \leq 1} ||\langle x, v \rangle u||_{2} \\
&= \sup_{||x||_2 \leq 1} |\langle x, v \rangle |. ||u||_{2}\\
&= ||u||_2. \sup_{||x||_2 \leq 1} |\langle x, v \rangle |\\
&= ||u||_2 .||v||_2 \;\;\;\;\text{(By Cauchy Schwarz)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $M$ is given by

$$
M = u\otimes v^* = uv^* = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
u_1v^*\\
\vdots\\
u_n v^*
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The goal is to find the maximum eigenvalue of $M^*M$. Since $\|u\|_2 = 1$, we have

$$
M^*M = \sum_{i=1}^n |u_i|^2 vv^* = vv^*
$$

Observing that $(vv^*)v = v(v^*v) = v$, it follows that $\lambda = 1$ is the only nonzero eigenvalue of $M^*M$ since $vv^*$ is rank $1$. Hence $\|M\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(M^*M)} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\eqalign{
 \|u\otimes v^*\|_F^2 &= (u\otimes v^*)^*:(u\otimes v^*) \cr
   &= (u^*\otimes v):(u\otimes v^*) \cr
   &= (u^*:u)\otimes(v:v^*) \cr
   &= \|u\|_F^2 \otimes \|v\|_F^2 \cr
   &= 1 \otimes 1 \cr
   &= 1 \cr
}$$